# Trouble with nulls in queries

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

```
sql = select * from [Table1] where [Num]=? and [Date]=? and [Name]=?

If name Is DBNull.Value OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(name.ToString) Then

     sql = "select * from [Table1] where [Num]=? and [Date]=? and [Name] is null"

End If
```

The code above works fine for awhile. When another different date value is passed to the `[Date]` field, it doesn't return the records if the `[Name]` (which is a text field) is null.

Otherwise, if the `[Name]` is not null, it works. I have to show the records where the `[Name]` field is null.

As a side question: Playing with these annoying nulls is driving me crazy. I'm considering replacing all nulls with empty strings, `""` or `" "`, but what are the pros and cons here, if there's any difference.

Comment: @J:Fake? I do use parameters, but decided to not to show it for simplicity and clarity, as I believe the problem is with the sql statements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do like this

```
sql = select * 
      from [Table1] 
      where [Num]=numParam 
          and [Date]=dateParam 
          and ([Name]=nameParam or nameParam is null)
```

Comment: Note that this works, but makes for a rather poorly performing query. There are better solutions.

Comment: "There are better solutions" Sir, I can't find one as of now.

Comment: @Nerdsworth Constructing your parameterized query conditionally is probably the best way.  ie : `If Name.HasValue Then sql.Append("AND [Name]=?") Else sql.Append("AND [Name] IS NULL")`